# My SVG "StateSignal13" is still shown after triggering. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, svg

My SVG "StateSignal13" is still shown after triggering Bestätigung_ÖFFNET and  Bestätigung_SCHLIESSET. Visibility doesn't work at all. What's wrong?

```js
var LE1BO = LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.getVariable("Siemens LOGO 8 NR1.Bestätigung_ÖFFNET");
var LE1BS = LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.getVariable("Siemens LOGO 8 NR1.Bestätigung_SCHLIESSET");

function ZustandLE1(){

    if (LE1BO == "True") {
                        LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.setVariable("Intern.ZustandLE1","True");
                        LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.setProperty("LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.StateSignal13.visibility", "visible");
    }else {
            LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.setProperty("LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.StateSignal13.visibility", "hidden");
            }
    
    if (LE1BS == "True") {
        LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.setVariable("Intern.ZustandLE1","False");
        LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.setProperty("LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.StateSignal13.visibility", "visible");
    }else {
            LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.setProperty("LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.StateSignal13.visibility", "hidden");
            }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some further insight on `LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg `.
is it a variable referring to an HTML element?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what type `LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg` is representing.
But assuming it's an HTML element the setProperty function is not applied correctly.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) of it.
If you want to adjust the styling of your element you will need to access it like so:

```
LeitstandSCHENKERRadeburg.style.setProperty('visibility', 'hidden')
```

Comment: THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP. YOU ARE GREAT. MY PROJECT IS ON! BTW, I´m new here and don´t know how can I rate you or give some rewards for your help.

Comment: @RajmundJanuszewski over time you will earn more StackOverflow reputation points. This will enable new features for you.